# Making a data frame of count of NA by variable for multiple data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I have a list containing 4 data frames:

`> names(listofdf)
[1] "q12014local"    "q12014national" "q22014local"    "q22014national"`

All the data frames have the same variable names . I want to make a new data frame which counts the number of NAs by variable and by data frame. The resulting output should look like this:

```
               v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7
q12014local    328   278   1786  0     0     12    1
q12014national  0    100   124   0     0     7     0
q22014local     0    0     0     0     0     289   0
q22014national  423  0     10    10    78    0     0
```

Here's a reproducible example:

`> df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1:5), v2 = c("apple", "pear", NA, "peaches", NA), v3 = c("sunday", "monday", NA, NA, NA))`

`> df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c(2, 7, NA, NA, "9"), v2 = c("plum", NA, "kiwi", NA, "jackfruit"), v3 = c(NA, NA, "saturday", NA, "wednesday"))`

`> df3 <- data.frame(v1 = c(12, NA, NA, NA, 8), v2 = c("pineapple", "guava", "lytchee", NA, NA), v3 = c("tuesday", "thursday", "friday", NA, "monday"))`

`> listofdf <- list(df1, df2, df3)`

So far I've been using `lapply(listofdf, function(x) table(is.na(x[, 15])))` to check the NAs of each data frame in the list and this is cumbersome !

Comment: I guess the names of `listofdf` would be the `first 3`. BTW, you created `NA` as strings.  Is it the case in your original dataset?

Comment: Hey, no, the NAs are not strings in real data- they are actual NAs.

Comment: In that case, you could use the second option ie. `is.na(x)`

Comment: You should never have NA values that aren't classed as such.

Comment: corrected in example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example showed, `NAs` are strings.

```
 names(listofdf) <- c("q12014local" , "q12014national", "q22014local")
 as.data.frame(t(sapply(listofdf, function(x) colSums(x=='NA'))))
 #                v1 v2 v3
 #q12014local     0  2  3
 #q12014national  2  2  3
 #q22014local     3  2  1
```

For real `NAs`

```
 t(sapply(listofdf, function(x) colSums(is.na(x))))
```

Comment: your answer is right but something very funny is happening ! in the matrix with the count of NA by variable, the count is being interchanged for variable names. i'm seeing the count of v3 under v1. I subsetted the data frame from the list and checked count again and it reports the correct number. but within the list, the variable name changes. Do i have to position match all columns before combining data frames into the list?

Comment: @vagabond In the example provided, I am not finding that anomaly.  Is it the output of `sapply(listofdf, function(x) colSums(x=='NA'))`?  If that is the case, you need to take the `t`.