# Testing whether n% of data values exist in a variable grouped by posix date

Tags: r, loops, na

I have a data frame that has hourly observational climate data over multiple years, I have included a dummy data frame below that will hopefully illustrate my QU.

```
 dateTime <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"),
                      as.POSIXct("2012-12-31"), 
                      by=(60*60))
 WS <- sample(0:20,8761,rep=TRUE)
 WD <- sample(0:390,8761,rep=TRUE)
 Temp <- sample(0:40,8761,rep=TRUE)
 df <- data.frame(dateTime,WS,WD,Temp)
 df$WS[WS>15] <- NA
```

I need to group by year (or in this example, by month) to find if df$WS has 75% or more of valid data for that month. My filtering criteria is NA as 0 is still a valid observation. I have real NAs as it is observational climate data.

I have tried dplyr piping using %>% function to filer by a new column "Month" as well as reviewing several questions on here
[Calculate the percentages of a column in a data frame - "grouped" by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716269/calculate-the-percentages-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-grouped-by-column),
[Making a data frame of count of NA by variable for multiple data frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743822/making-a-data-frame-of-count-of-na-by-variable-for-multiple-data-frames-in-a-lis),
[R group by date, and summarize the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575785/r-group-by-date-and-summarize-the-values)

None of these have really answered my question.

My hope is to put something in a longer script that works in a looping function that will go through all my stations and all the years in each station to produce a wind rose if this criteria is met for that year / station. Please let me know if I need to clarify more.
Cheers

Comment: Valid data for which variable, `Temp`?

Comment: The variable is $WS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way of doing this. This one appears quite instructive.

First create a new variable which will denote month (and account for year if you have more than one year). Split on this variable and count the number of NAs. Divide this by the number of values and multiply by 100 to get percentage points.

```
df$monthyear <- format(df$dateTime, format = "%m %Y")

out <- split(df, f = df$monthyear)

sapply(out, function(x) (sum(is.na(x$WS))/nrow(x)) * 100)

 01 2012  02 2012  03 2012  04 2012  05 2012  06 2012  07 2012 
23.92473 21.40805 24.09152 25.00000 20.56452 24.58333 27.15054 
 08 2012  09 2012  10 2012  11 2012  12 2012 
22.31183 25.69444 23.22148 21.80556 24.96533
```

You could also use `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, (sum(is.na(WS))/.N) * 100, by = monthyear]

    monthyear       V1
 1:   01 2012 23.92473
 2:   02 2012 21.40805
 3:   03 2012 24.09152
 4:   04 2012 25.00000
 5:   05 2012 20.56452
 6:   06 2012 24.58333
 7:   07 2012 27.15054
 8:   08 2012 22.31183
 9:   09 2012 25.69444
10:   10 2012 23.22148
11:   11 2012 21.80556
12:   12 2012 24.96533
```

Comment: Both functions worked for me, it seems simple. Thanks. Using data.table I can now hopefully give a IF function in my loop to produce my graphs. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `dplyr`. It will work even if you have missing data.

```
library(lubridate) #for the days_in_month function
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(Month=format(dateTime,"%Y-%m")) %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(No.Obs=sum(!is.na(WS)),
            Max.Obs=24*days_in_month(as.Date(paste0(first(Month),"-01")))) %>% 
  mutate(Obs.Rate=No.Obs/Max.Obs)

df2
     Month No.Obs Max.Obs  Obs.Rate
     <chr>  <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2012-01    575     744 0.7728495
 2 2012-02    545     696 0.7830460
 3 2012-03    560     744 0.7526882
 4 2012-04    537     720 0.7458333
 5 2012-05    567     744 0.7620968
 6 2012-06    557     720 0.7736111
 7 2012-07    553     744 0.7432796
 8 2012-08    568     744 0.7634409
 9 2012-09    546     720 0.7583333
10 2012-10    544     744 0.7311828
11 2012-11    546     720 0.7583333
12 2012-12    554     744 0.7446237
```

Comment: The Max.Obs is variable as not all days are complete (especially at the front of the data depending on when the station began recording) and     days_in_month(as.Date(paste0(first(Month),"-01")))   is also variable between stations. Is there a way around that in your suggestion?